# Vim's surround plugin usage

Tags: vim, plugins

I just downloaded vim today.

The [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) [plugin](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-surround-vim/) documentation says:

> Press `cs"'` inside `"Hello world!"` to change it to `'Hello world!'`.

But where am I supposed to press `cs"'` and in which mode?

Comment: it also says that I should type it in normal mode but in normal mode i can just type c it doesn't allows me to type more

Comment: I voted the "Hello, World" answer up, but lemme just say this. I do PHP/HTML/CSS development at my day job, and surround.vim + allml.vim have made my life incredibly easier. I can't recommend vim those two plugin highly enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just downloaded vim?  You've made the right choice!

Vim has several modes.

Insert mode is what you use to actually type text.  It is *not* what you use to move around the document ( in vim terms, the 'buffer' ).

After you have typed "Hello world":

hit ESC to go to Command mode.

use the 'hjkl' keys to move the cursor inside the quotes.

then type cs"' to Change Surrounds from " to '

Vim's online help is excellent.

In Command mode, type :help surround to get the help for the plugin

if you see nothing doing that, first try :help helptags , which will tell you how to setup the help files ( surround plugin also has excellent help )

Comment: When I'm in normal mode I type cs and the cursor goes to the bottom left of vim's window and after that I can't type anymore. I can only type more if I type ":" first

Answer (score 3):

Start vim, enter insert mode, and type:

```
"Hello, world!"
```

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to get back to normal mode, and go left at least once, now press `cs"'` and it'll change to:

```
'Hello, world!'
```

(I just installed surround and tried this exactly, Ubuntu-packaged vim 7.2 with my own .vimrc and plugins, but nothing that should affect this.)

Comment: Note: I'm relatively new to vim and Just Use It(tm) to Get Shit Done(tm), so I might be off on a few terms, such as "normal mode" might really be "command mode" here.